# Simulate data in R from a linear model where the parameters are correlated

Tags: r, simulation

I would like to simulate data from the follow model in R

```
Y ~ N(b0 + b1*X, sigma)
```

and fit the following model in R

```
lm(Y ~ 1 + X, data)
```

roughly here is what the R code would be,

```
nsims = 1000
X = 1:50 
b0 = rnorm(nsims, 55.63, 31.40)
b1 = rnorm(nsims, 1.04, .39)
sigma = rnorm(nsims, 11.34, 4.11)
```

The catch is that I'd like `b0`, `b1`, and `sigma` to be correlated. I'd like them to have this for a correlation.

```
R <- matrix(c(1, .16, .54, 
              .16, 1, .13,
              .54, .13, 1),
              nrow = 3)
colnames(R) <- c("b0", "b1", "sigma")
```

Now given that I want this correlation structure, my `rnorm` code above is wrong. If my data didn't need this correlation matrix, I would probably do the following,

```
 sim_data <- data.frame()
 for(i in 1:nsims){
   Y = b0[i] + b1[i]*X + rnorm(length(X), 0, sigma[i]) 
   data_tmp <- data.frame(Y = Y, X = X, ID = i)
   sim_data <- rbind(sim_data, data_tmp)
 }
```

But this ignores my correlation structure because of the way I generated the parameters. Can anyone offer me some suggestions or pointers where to look for how to incorporate a correlation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simulate 3-dimensional normal distribution and take variables from it. You can use `MASS` package for multivariate simulation and `MBESS` package for transformation from correlation to covariance matric which is needed in `mvrnorm` function.

```
library(MASS)
library(MBESS)
R <- matrix(c(1, .16, .54,
              .16, 1, .13,
              .54, .13, 1),
            nrow = 3)
SD <- c(31.40, .39, 4.11)
## convert correlation matrix to covariance matrix
Cov <- cor2cov(R, SD)
### you can also do it algebraically without MBESS package
### Cov <- SD %*% t(SD) * R 
### where %*% is matrix multiplication and * is normal multiplication
### t() is transpose function

# simulate multivariate normal distribution
mvnorm <- mvrnorm(
  1000,
  mu = c(55.63, 1.04, 11.34),
  Sigma = Cov,
  empirical = T
)
# check whether correlation matrix is right
cor(mvnorm)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1.00 0.16 0.54
[2,] 0.16 1.00 0.13
[3,] 0.54 0.13 1.00
# extract variables
b0 <- mvnorm[, 1]
b1 <- mvnorm[, 2]
sigma <- mvnorm[, 3]
```